# Error en la librería JEP de Java

Tags: java, jepp

Tengo el siguiente código que estoy utilizando para evaluar funciones matemáticas en cierto punto, consta de tres clases:

datos.java

```
package clases;
public class datos {
    String variable = "", funcion = "";
    int n = 0;
    int limInf = 0, limSup = 0;

    public datos(String var, String fun, int n, int limIn, int limSup){
        this.funcion = fun;
        this.limInf = limIn;
        this.limSup = limSup;
        this.n = n;
        this.variable = var;
    }

    public String getVariable() {
        return variable;
    }

    public String getFuncion() {
        return funcion;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public int getLimInf() {
        return limInf;
    }

    public int getLimSup() {
        return limSup;
    }
}
```

evaluacion.java

```
package metodos;

import org.nfunk.jep.JEP;

public class evaluacion {
    String variable = "", funcion = "";
    double valor = 0;

    public evaluacion(String funcion, String variable, double valor){
        this.funcion = funcion;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.variable = variable;
    }

    public double evaluarElementoEn(){
        JEP j = new JEP();
        j.addStandardConstants();
        j.addStandardFunctions();
        j.addConstant(this.variable, this.valor);
        j.parseExpression(this.funcion);

        if(j.hasError()){
            System.out.println(j.getErrorInfo()); // Imprimir error.
        }
        return j.getValue();
    }
}
```

main.java

```
package main;

import clases.datos;
import metodos.evaluacion;

public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        datos d = new datos("x","sin(x)",1,0,5);
        for(int i = d.getLimInf(); i <= d.getLimSup(); i++){
            evaluacion e = new evaluacion(d.getFuncion(),d.getVariable(),i);
            double resp = e.evaluarElementoEn();
            System.out.println("["+i+"] "+resp);
        }
    }
}
```

Al correr el programa por ejemplo, con la función "sin(x)" como argumento, tengo la siguiente salida:

```
run:
[0] 0.0
[1] 0.8414709848078965
[2] 0.9092974268256817
[3] 0.1411200080598672
[4] -0.7568024953079282
[5] -0.9589242746631385
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Ahora, calculando aparte el seno de cada uno de los números, desde 0 hasta 5, tengo que:

```
sen(0) = 0
sen(1) = 0.0174
sen(2) = 0.0348
sen(3) = 0.0523
sen(4) = 0.0697
sen(5) = 0.0871
```

Intuitivamente considero que dentro del método de evaluación existe un error a considerar, puesto a que el programa debe ser lo más exacto posible debo al menos reducir lo más que se pueda ese error, buscando la documentación del método no encuentro nada referente a esto. Entonces aquí la cuestión es ya sea calcular el error de manera independiente o buscar algún método alternativo que me ayude a corregir ese error, cabe señalar que este error se presenta al analizar funciones trigonométricas, con funciones lineales no sucede.

Comment: Lo habitual es que el argumento de las funciones trigonométricas sea en *radianes*, pero los valores que has calculado aparte parece que están calculados usando grados. Calculando el valor de "sin(1)" en radianes coincide con el valor que muestra tu programa.

Comment: Gracias, era eso, no había considerado la conversión de grados a radianes.